# meaning of "about as about as"

Tags: meaning

The following is an excerpt from the CNN news of October 16.
What does "this is about as about as close to a dream scenario ..." mean? Two "about"s have confused me.
How can you paraphrase this?

"Trump not only refused to condemn the QAnon conspiracy theory, but he claimed (again) to be ignorant of the movement, much to the disbelief of Guthrie. Then, after claiming not to know much about QAnon, the president actually praised the virtual cult for being 'very strongly against pedophilia.' NBC's resident QAnon reporter Ben Collins noted, 'Outside of a straight up endorsement, this is about as about as close to a dream scenario for QAnon followers as is humanly possible.'"

Comment: It's a tupo!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The extra *about* is either another level of misdirection or a simple case of repeating a phrase the speaker was anxious to insert. The context tells us the emotions were high enough to ensure the emotions were very high and the background ensures the intellect was unaware of such subtleties as repeating a phrase for emphasis.